# Would this be called a complex?

Tags: proteins

When an intermediate is formed between a substrate and an enzyme, this is called an enzyme-substrate complex.

When a molecule is bound to its respective transfer protein, (the molecule being transported is unchanged when released from the protein at the destination) would this be called a complex? If not, what would this be called?

Comment: Yes, it's a complex. Anything bound to anything else in biochemistry is a complex, especially when you're talking about proteins. The bonds need not be covalent, either.

Comment: The same way we call "receptor-ligand complex"; "transcription preinitiation complex", "nuclear pore complex" et cetera. The word 'complex' used in more-than one sense in biology; not always necessarily as co-ordination complex.

Comment: Welcome to Biology SE. You could visit the [tour-page](http://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) for basic informations, the [help-page](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help) for more detailed informations about what [could be asked](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [could not be](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). For formatting tasks in command prompt, visit [this](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) help sub-page. Thanks